# Tab bar controller controller color change

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

In my application i want to change the tab bar controller color,How to assign a custom color to the tab bar controller lik uinavigation bar  in ios6?Can any one give me some refrences?

Comment: you want to apply the  custom tabbar icon changes ? if yes then you need to create Custom TabBar.

Answer (score 2):

Put this on app delegate:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It's better than the first answer because it also changes the edit view tint color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setTintColor option as described

```
[tabbarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

or you can set the background image

```
[tabbarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg.png"];
```

if your TabBarController is defined int the AppDelegate you may need additional coding to access it.

First to set the background image

```
[[[[(UITabBarController *)[[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] rootViewController]tabBar]setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg.png"]]]];
```

Second to set the tintcolor if required

```
[[[[(UITabBarController *)[[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] rootViewController]tabBar]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]]];
```

dont forget to import your AppDelegate.h file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this call

```
tabbarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

To change only tabBar color, you can achieve by this:

```
tabbarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

But, for more, you need to create Custom TabBar and can do with it like color change, custom tabbar icon changes, etc.

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Approach that worked for me (tested in iOS6) is:

```
[[UITabBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

in AppDelegate.h file in method `application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. Try this if it's still actual. I see the question still stays unsolved.